# Gittle. How to get a true list of modified files?

Tags: python, git

I try to get a list of all modified files like this:

```
 repo_path = '.'
 repo_url = 'git@github.com:username/myfolder.git'
 repo = Gittle(repo_path, origin_uri = repo_url)
 repo.modified_files
```

But the list of files I get is rather huge and contains garbage. In fact, it has nothing to do with the list that I get if I run in console:

```
 $ git status
```

So, my question is how to get a true list of modified files with `Gittle` library. I want this list in order to perform addition and commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are executing from the wrong path.

```
import os
path = '/path/to/repo' # or use input from command line
savedPath = os.getcwd()

# do init stuff

os.chdir(path)

# do repo stuff
repo_path = '.'
repo_url = 'git@github.com:username/myfolder.git'
repo = Gittle(repo_path, origin_uri=repo_url)

print repo.modified_files

# finish repo stuff

os.chdir(savedPath)

# do other stuff
```

Comment: Thanks! I will check it soon and report back!